# Steam installation library in other storage device

Tags: steam, storage, media

I tried to install games from Steam in another storage media.

```
(process:19380): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:11:39.869: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
reaping pid: 19523 -- gameoverlayui
Couldn't write /snap/bare/5/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /boot/efi/.steam_exec_test.sh: Permission denied
Couldn't write /snap/brave/257/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core18/2785/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core20/1974/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core22/607/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core22/858/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/discord/155/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/gnome-42-2204/126/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/gnome-42-2204/87/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/pycharm-community/342/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/snap-store/959/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/snapd/18933/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/snapd/19457/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
reaping pid: 19380 -- gameoverlayui
reaping pid: 19524 -- gameoverlayui
reaping pid: 19525 -- gameoverlayui
reaping pid: 19526 -- gameoverlayui
```

The game will install, but it will not run. I think it's because of this. Do you have any idea why it is not able to do this?

Comment: You don't mention what command the log outputs you show are related to, but I'm not sure they are a problem. What game are you trying to launch? Is it the same for all games? Do they work when installed in the standard Steam library location?